# AJAX not saving variables to javascript (asynchronous issues)

Tags: ajax, asynchronous

Why is alert saying that the `text[0]` is `undefined`?

This is my code:

```
var text = new Array;
$.ajax({
   url: 'engine1/api.php', 
   data: "", 
   dataType: 'json', 
   success: function(rows){
      text = rows;
   } 
});
alert(text[0]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var text = new Array;
$.ajax({
   url: 'engine1/api.php', 
   data: "", 
   dataType: 'json', 
   success: function(rows){
      text = rows;
      alert(text[0]); // will work, this gets executed after you set text
   } 
});
//alert(text[0]); << don't put this here, it will get executed right after you send the request
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally answered my own question, for anyone that comes across this question, here is what I did:

Because ajax is asynchronous, `alert(text[0])` is getting executed before `text=rows`.

You can set ajax to run procedurally like this:

`$.ajax({
    url: 'engine1/api.php', 
    data: "", 
    dataType: 'json', 
    async: false;
    success: function(rows){...`

Apperently this is one of the few cases that you can/should set ajax to `async:false` (because you're serving javascript/jquery to the client).

Comment: there's no reason to remove async, the alert should just be in the onsuccess continuation